# Error in Zend validator: "Internal Error: DNS validation failed"

Tags: validation, zend-framework

I am having the following problem with my magento install (version 1.3.2.3):

When someone tries to check out with an @bluewin.ch email address the following error is produced:

```
URL: https://www.example.com/checkout/onepage/
Time: 2014-11-13 14:38:03 GMT
Error:
Internal error: DNS validation failed

Trace:
#0 /lib/Zend/Validate/EmailAddress.php(184): Zend_Validate_Hostname->isValid('bluewin.ch')
#1 /lib/Zend/Validate.php(157): Zend_Validate_EmailAddress->isValid('nothing@bluewin...')
#2 /app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php(674): Zend_Validate::is('nothing@bluewin...', 'EmailAddress')
#3 /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(251): Mage_Customer_Model_Customer->validate()
#4 /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Type/Onepage.php(195): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->_processValidateCustomer(Object(Mxperts_NoRegion_Model_Quote_Address))
#5 /app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php(253): Mage_Checkout_Model_Type_Onepage->saveBilling(Array, false)
#6 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(376): Mage_Checkout_OnepageController->saveBillingAction()
#7 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(248): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('saveBilling')
#8 /app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(158): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#9 /app/Mage.php(459): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#10 /index.php(72): Mage::run()
#11 {main}
```

When I dig a bit deeper, I find the following line is throwing the error:

```
// Check each domain part
$status = @preg_match($regexLabel, $domainPart);
if ($status === false) {
    /**
     * Regex error
     * @see Zend_Validate_Exception
     */
    #require_once 'Zend/Validate/Exception.php';
    throw new Zend_Validate_Exception('Internal error: DNS validation failed');
} elseif ($status === 0) {
    $valid = false;
}
```

This is lines 354-365 of `/lib/Zend/Validate/Hostename.php`

I can tell you that the values of pattern and subject of the `preg_match` are as follows at the moment this error is thrown:

```
$regexLabel = '/^[a-z0-9\x{00EO}-\x{00F6}\x{00F8}-\x{00FF}\x{0153}\x2d]{1,63}$/iu';
$domainPart = 'bluewin';
```

However, I have no idea why this `preg_match` would return `false`

As a little side note: the presence or absence of the `u` modifier make no difference.

Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed!

Thanks in advance!
nanos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the error:

The regex is not valid because `\x{00EO}` is not a valid hex character. The correct character must be `\x{00E0}`. If anyone is interested the change must be made in this file:

`lib/Zend/Validate/Hostname/Ch.php`

Thanks for you help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand the problem. Let me explain why:

`[]` is a group of symbols to check agains, this part is 1 - 63 chars long.

bluewin matches against `^[a-z0-9]{1,63}$`, so my assumption is, that `\x{00EO}-\x{00F6}\x{00F8}-\x{00FF}\x{0153}\x2d` removed symbols from the group. Which doesn't make sense in my mind.

Comment: Thanks Fabian. Unfortunately I must admit I don't fully understand your answer. I must admit that I'm a bit weak with regex, so I really don't really understand this expression.

The thing is, though, that this code worked for years, and there are plenty of customers with @bluewin.ch addresses in our database, so something must have changed here. I'm kind of in a mind to disable this check and just let almost everything through except for the most basic kind of check, but I don't like stuff I don't understand...